# Integrating bitmovin player in chrome cast custom receiver web app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, bitmovin-player

I am trying to integrate bitmovin player with custom reciver web app but i could not control the player once casted.
How to remotely control the player using the sender?

Comment: Can you provide more details please, your question is not clear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Bitmovin Player set up in your sender app, you need to enable casting support using [config.remotecontrol](https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/api-reference/web/web-sdk-v8-api-player-configuration#/player/web/8/docs/interfaces/core_config.googlecastremotecontrolconfig.html) configuration. Please set `type: 'googlecast'`, `receiverApplicationId: 'your-custom-receiver-app-id',` and you will likely need to set the receiver version to v3 (aka Google Cast Application Framework (CAF)) using `receiverVersion: 'v3'` (v2 is deprecated by Google for new apps).

For the cast receiver, I'd recommend starting with [Bitmovin's sample receiver app](https://github.com/bitmovin/bitmovin-player-caf-receiver/) as it contains code to handle more advanced use cases (like DRM support). Build the project and publish a cast application pointing to it should be all you need (make sure to use this app ID in the sender app's player configuration as mentioned in the previous paragraph).